# Upload scipt on PyPI to get a CLI program

Tags: python, bash, command-line-interface, pypi

I'm looking for the way to upload my script on PyPI and make it available to install with pip. I'd to be able to run it from terminal without using the python command and not caring about the working directory. For example use it as folllow:

```sh
$mypythonprogram --option [arguments]
```

I only found the way to make my script used as a package so far..

Comment: You don't need to upload your script to PyPI to be able to use it as a command. And doing so wouldn't solve your problem even if you could upload your code to PyPI.  It looks like you are making the [XY problem](https://xyproblem.info/) mistake. See if the results from googling "package python program" help. In particular, start with https://docs.python-guide.org/shipping/packaging/.

Comment: You need to declare `scripts` or `entry_points` in your `setup.py`. See https://docs.python.org/3/distutils/setupscript.html#installing-scripts and https://packaging.python.org/guides/distributing-packages-using-setuptools/#scripts

Answer (score 0):

Following [this tutorial](https://levelup.gitconnected.com/how-to-publish-a-python-command-line-application-to-pypi-5b97a6d586f1) using poetry it did exactly what I wanted. The package can be installed with a simple pip install command and be run as a simple command line.